# What is the relationship of components, variables, functions of an Actor Blueprint and Event Graph from C++ standpoint?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5

Though I have a basic knowledge of `C++` language and I've been using Unreal Engine for quite a long time but I feel uncertain what happens behind the scenes of an actor blueprint, specifically the relationship between its components, functions, variables and Event Graph 
I always assume that (let's take a character Blueprint `BP_ThirdPersonCharacter` for example):
(1) "the GLOBAL character BP" is "a GLOBAL `C++` class (or equivalent)" that inherits from all sub classes (which are indeed sub blueprints - which will instantiate components (in the picture) )
(2) adding functions is just like adding functions for the GLOBAL BP (or class) above.
(3) the same logic for adding variables, meaning adding variable members for the GLOBAL BP/class.
=>meaning (1), (2), (3) seem to matches `C++` standpoint 100%
--------------------------
+But what about the Event Graph, what role it plays from `C++` standpoint?
+Any answer that points out I was wrong anywhere would be also great help :)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so this is my very first answer in stackoverflow so I will try my best here.
I think you got everything there pretty much right, except the "inherits from all sub classes" point. In inheritance you don't inherit functionality from a subclass, it is the subclass that inherits from the parent class. But that was probably a typo.

Now, to your question: Think about Graphs like *.cpp files for the same *.h file. A Graph doesn't really have an equivalent in C++ because in C++ you will write all your operational and gameplay logic in a single *.cpp for a given class. But if you think about it, doing it entirely in the Blueprint (specially if it is a class with a lot of functionality) will make your graph too huge and confusing. That's why you can create multiple Graphs. You can have one for your basic events like BeginPlay() and Tick(), just like the image you uploaded, and another Graph named CustomEvents to handle events created by you like PlayerDeath() or OnPowerUpPickup() for example. In a .cpp file this would be all in the same file, in Blueprint you have this extra functionality to help you to organize things.
Just note that you cannot create equal events in different Graphs. For example, if you happen to have your BeginPlay() defined in the EventGraph, then you created a new Graph called MyGraph and tried to create BeginPlay() in there again Unreal will automatically jump you to the BeginPlay() event created in the EventGraph. Even if you try CtrlC+CtrlV the BeginPlay() node, Unreal will create a new CustomEvent node instead.

I hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thank you pretty much, It is absolutely the answer I'm looking for, besh wish! :)